# Forking Rails Tutorial sample_app for Rails 4

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to fork Michael Hartl's sample_app_rails_4 (https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4). I keep getting the error message:

> 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights and the repository exists'

after entering the following commands.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone git@github.com:railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4.git
```

I appreciate any help in getting this (seemingly simple) step to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SSH is not an option on that repository.  Try

git clone https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4.git

Not actually forking, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fork the repo, get it in your personal GitHub repository, and then clone the version that is in your personal repo.  Here is a GitHub article on forking and cloning: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Here are the steps at a high level:

1. Go to Hartl's repo and click fork.  This will copy the project in your GitHub account.
2. Clone the repo from your personal account:

`$ git clone git@github.com:your_github_usernamesample_app_rails_4.git`